# How to remove input method from android's TextView context menu

Tags: android, xml, textview, contextmenu, android-contextmenu

I have a context menu on a `TextView` representing a user name in my app. When the `context menu` appears I want to have certain options such as *View Statistics* etc. The `context menu` is appearing fine and everything is working great except it's adding *Input method* to the `context menu` and I do not want it there. It's irrelevant to what the context menu is there for and there is not text entry. How can I remove this item from the `context menu`? I've tried removing `item 0` in the context menu and adding

```
android:editable="false"
```

to the `XML` file to no avail. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about `menu.removeItem(android.R.id.switchInputMethod);`?

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much, it worked like a charm. I knew there had to be a way.

Comment: can you tell me how to get the "menu"?it is your  Customize,i want to get system context menu

Answer (score 0):

Im pretty sure that isn't possible, the input method is how the user changes the current IME (soft keyboard) if the have multiple keyboards installed.  Its a global setting.